# How use --out parameter with mongodump command in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to take the backup of database in MongoDb 3.0 using Out Parameter.
My command is:
mongodump --dbpath /data/db/ --out /data/backup/

But when i execute this command i faced an error that is:

error parsing command line options: --dbpath and related flags are n
t supported in 3.0 tools.
ee http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/tools-dbpath-deprecated for more information

I don't know how to resolve this. 
can anyone explain how use --out parameter with mongodump command in MongoDB 3.0

Answer (score 2):

- default

  mongodump  --port port_name -d db_name --out path_dir
- example

  mongodump  --port 4001 -d machine --out ~/Desktop/test_data/

Answer (score 0):

`--dbpath` is removed from the MongoDb 3.0 mongodump parameter list. That should have specified the location of your dbs. Try omitting the parameter, it should read the data from your mongod instance.

If you are not managing try setting the [storageOptions](http://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/configuration-options/#storage.dbPath).